# Object 3D rotation using png's

Tags: xcode, animation, memory, uiimageview

I want to achieve an object 3D rotation in Xcode that instead of using openGL uses a set of prerendered pngs. This would allow for much more complex 3D animations in terms of polygons and light effects. So far I have achieved to build subclass of UIView that contains a UIScrollView and in the scrollViewDidScroll delegate method it scrubs through 360 png images depending on the content offset of the UIScrollView. This does exactly what I want to achieve except a few major problems.

I've tried three different methods to swap the images.

Method 1:
When the View is being initialized I put all UIImages in UIImageViews and those on screen with alpha = 0 and then set the respective imageView's alpha to 1 on scrollViewDidScroll

Method 2:
When the View is being initialized I put all UIImages in an array and put a single UIImageView on screen. In scrollViewDidScroll I set the respective image from the array as the image of the UIImageView

Method 3:
When the View is being initialized I save all imageNames in an Array and put a sing UIImageView on the screen. In scrollViewDidScroll I create a UIImage with the name from the array for the respective index and set this as the image for my UIImageView

All three are very memory consuming and will eventually cause memory warnings or crashes. While method three is slightly less memory expensive it's also a lot laggier.

Is there any method to do this memory efficient and fast without having to use openGL??

Edit: Theodore Gray achieved this in his Elements app in an awesome way and I can't find out how. See here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHiEqf5wb3g&feature=player_embedded

Comment: So, effectively, you want to play a short video clip that you pre-composed from individual PNG frames?

Comment: Not exactly so the animationImages property of UIImageView won't do the trick. I would need to be able to jump to a certain frame of the animation depending on the UIScrollView contentOffset.